# How to set delay for buttons color change

Tags: java, android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

take = getIntent();
levelone = take.getIntArrayExtra("level1");
take = getIntent();
leveltwo = take.getIntArrayExtra("level2");
take = getIntent();
levelthree = take.getIntArrayExtra("level3");
colors[0] = (R.drawable.blue1);//Suppose to give integer value for the colors
colors[1] = (R.drawable.purple1);
colors[2] = (R.drawable.yellow1);
colors[3] = (R.drawable.green1);
colors1[0] = (R.drawable.blue);//Suppose to set the colors back to origin
colors1[1] = (R.drawable.purple);
colors1[2] = (R.drawable.yellow);
colors1[3] = (R.drawable.green);


purple = findViewById(R.id.purplee);   //1
green = findViewById(R.id.greenn);//2
yellow = findViewById(R.id.yelloww);//3
blue = findViewById(R.id.bluee);//4

for (int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    buttons[i] = findViewById(btn[i]);
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
}
        buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(colors[1]);//purple Butttons[1]
buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(colors[2]);//Yellow Buttons[2]
buttons[3].setBackgroundResource(colors[3]);//Green Buttons[3]
buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(colors[0]);//Blue Buttons[0]

//  Blue Buttons[0],purple Butttons[1] ,Yellow Buttons[2],Green Buttons[3]
//colors[0]==Blue  ,colors[1]==purple,colors[2]==Green,colors[3]==Yellow


         //Set background button color}

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           /* buttons[0].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); //Suppose to change the color to the primary color*/
            for(int i=0;i<levelone.length;i++)
            {
                buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(colors[1]);

            }
        }
    }, 1000);//Set the delay between changes of colors
```

I want to change the buttons color by delay so I ran a couple of options to do so and none of them worked, I mean I didn't see the delay and the color of the buttons didn't change as it supposed to so how should I do that?
In the code, I have tried something but it didn't work so if you have any ideas I will be happy to hear.

Comment: Can you explain more the delay that you want to achieve? Looking at your postDelayed, it's will only delay the first time

Comment: I want to set delay between the color changes , so I need it to set delay for each time that the color button changes , so I don't think postDelayed will be opertional in here

Comment: @user3943358 see the change i made in the answer

Comment: please use **recursive method** with the size of `colors[]` and use postDelayed in recursive method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transition drawables can help you. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
</transition>
```

In your view, you can reference the above like this `android:background="@drawable/transition_drawable"`

Then in your code, you can do something like this to activate forward transition (reverse transition is possible too) :

`((TransitionDrawable) view.getBackground()).startTransition(2000);`

The above will start smooth transition between two colors within 2000 msecs.

Comment: Yeah but one thing I didn't figure out is how to pick the color from the file , I have a list of colors I need to use

Answer (score 0):

when ever you want to change the color with delay use a Handler like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<levelone.length;i++)
{
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(colors[1]);
        }
    }, NUMBER_IN_MILLISECOND * i);
}
```

and you enter the number you want in milliseconds insread of NUMBER_IN_MILLISECOND

Answer (score 0):

```
    buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(colors[1]);//purple Butttons[1]
    buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(colors[2]);//Yellow Buttons[2]
    buttons[3].setBackgroundResource(colors[3]);//Green Buttons[3]
    buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(colors[0]);//Blue Buttons[0]

    //  Blue Buttons[0],purple Butttons[1] ,Yellow Buttons[2],Green Buttons[3]
    //colors[0]==Blue  ,colors[1]==purple,colors[2]==Green,colors[3]==Yellow


             //Set background button color}

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
    for(int i=0;i<levelone.length;i++)
    {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(colors1[1]);//purple Butttons[1]
                buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(colors1[2]);//Yellow Buttons[2]
                buttons[3].setBackgroundResource(colors1[3]);//Green Buttons[3]
                buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(colors1[0]);//Blue Buttons[0]


            }
        }, 1500 * i);
    }
```

I did it like this , I set a sequnce of colors that should work but it didn't . It still not seting the delay .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the delay between the color changes, you need to run `postDelayed` inside a loop and the loop must take in `colors` to avoid Exception:

```
for(int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(colors[i]);
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code written in this sample for changing the colors of a view continuously -
https://github.com/yadavshivam3000/ColorChangingTextView